# How get I get the last n characters of a wchar_t*

Tags: c, winapi

given something like:

```
wchar_t filename[] = L"program.exe";
```

how can I get the last 4 characters to test if ends with '.exe' or not?

Comment: Don't; use `_wsplitpath_s` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx

Comment: @Roger I went with this solution

Comment: A word of warning: File extensions are mostly meaningless. They are the least reliable meta information for actual file content.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the length of the array with `wcslen()` and compare with `wcscmp()`:

```
#include <wchar.h>

wchar_t filename[] = L"program.exe";

size_t len = wcslen(filename);
if (len >= 4 && !wcscmp(filename + len - 4, L".exe")) {
    /* the extension is .exe */
} else {
    /* filename too short or extension not .exe */
}
```

Unless you are developing for Windows, as the file extension suggests, I would strongly encourage you to stay away from `wchar_t` APIs and use UTF-8 encoding inside your program.

Comment: what should I be using instead of wchar_t ?

Comment: Windows uses wide-character APIs natively (`*W` variants), so deals with `wchar_t *` strings or equivalent `BSTR`/etc. types. The `*A` variants are not efficient and are only `ASCII` on the Windows platform, so will not handle UTF-8 encoded characters correctly.

Comment: Then if you cannot stay away from Windows as I do, convert the silly broken `wchar_t` arrays to UTF-8 inside your program and back to `wchar_t` when you need to talk to the OS.  This is only a hint, you can use all the standard functions from `<wchar.h>`, but it is a real pain.

Comment: Starting where the asker is, perhaps sticking to `wchar_t` is the most expedient

Comment: Fairly misleading advice there. On Windows, it is generally advisable to use UTF-16 throughout, and only convert to UTF-8, when data leaves the application. Common examples are network sockets, file streams, pipes, mailslots, and so on.

Comment: Misleading advice? I offer the correct answer and give sound advice for all platforms except Windows.  Microsoft is so consistent in making the wrong choices, especially annoying for C programmers: \ path separator, \r\n line terminations, UTF-16 encoding... not to mention their deliberate refusal to support C99 in their toolchain. UTF-16 offers no advantages over UTF-8: you still have to make specific code for full Unicode support. The OP will have to cope with UTF-16 for Windows APIs, but should learn to master UTF-8 for the rest of the world.

Comment: Wow, so much uninformed opinion, it hurts. Microsoft decided to go with UTF-16, because UTF-8 didn't exist, and their time machine just wasn't up to speed. `\r\n` is unarguably the **correct** way to encode a line terminator (see [Why is the line terminator CR+LF?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/18/91899.aspx)). Regardless of all that: When you're developing for Windows, it is best to use UTF-16 throughout the application. Suggesting to do otherwise is misleading.

Comment: @IInspectable: I agree with your conclusion and updated my answer accordingly. UTF-8 was finalized in 1993, before the WIN32 API was solidified and it's been long enough for Microsoft to have fixed their 8 bit APIs. `\r\n` was copied from CP/M, they could have ditched it as they did for the `^Z` end of file marker. MacOS used to have a confusing `\r`, they also changed their minds.  Let's stop this troll now.

Comment: @chqrlie: "1993 before Win32 was solidified" Huh?  Win32 (and with it, Unicode support in the Windows API) was introduced with Windows NT, which was **released** in 1993, meaning all the design decisions had been made years earlier.  Besides that, the invention of UTF-8 isn't the important point in time, but the expansion of Unicode beyond 16-bit code points.  Win32 didn't start out using UTF-16, but UCS-2, which didn't go away until 2011.